# Как сделать статический подкласс?

Tags: c#, классы

у меня есть 2 статических класса, содержащие методы

```
public static class SMS {
    
}
```

и

```
public static class Contacts {
    
}
```

я бы хотел создать статический класс Phone,
чтоб можно было ссылаться следующим образом:

```
Phone.SMS.SendSMS(phoneNumber, text);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Comment: Не надо такого хотеть. Как говорится: удачи с юнит-тестированием (злорадный смех)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очевидно, так:

```cs
public static class Phone 
{
    public static class SMS
    {
        public static void SendSMS(string phoneNumber, string text)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

[Проверка.](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUHgBQAsB7KAUwDoBlAWWpvKjjuoAoAiABnQ5gAIOgLBBADCCABEBGBhEEDcIBwCUAbjx5UAZn6pMANg3p+xMuX54A3nn4WN6zToz9W5y2dyXXVjdo0AWe0xb02TS5+AAdSCgA5CABbACNyMAEg/mByAA9gOUc3fmccnM0ATjYAEg5qPwBLKABze3pc1IyAXxSSUPCjEzDDKLiE5vklF3zm7P4x3GagA=)

---

Возможно, вам вместо класса `Phone` нужен `namespace Phone`?

Comment: Спасибо, что то не додумался

Comment: @Владислав: Пожалуйста, рад что помогло.

Comment: @VladD, `static` класс может быть `partial`? чтобы разделить на несколько файлов?

Comment: @Grundy может конечно

Comment: @Владислав Публичные вложенные типы - уже индикатор проблем проектирования, а если они при этом еще статические, то вообще страх и ужас. :) я тоже предполагаю, что вам нужен `namespace`, а не класс.